# Apache Isis: @Property(editing = Editing.ENABLED) doesn't work for ViewModels

Tags: isis

I added a property to ViewModel and marked it with Editing.ENABLED.

```
@DomainObject(
        nature = Nature.VIEW_MODEL,
        objectType = "homepage.HomePageViewModel"
)
public class HomePageViewModel {

    @Setter @Getter
    @Property(editing = Editing.ENABLED)
    private String editableField;

}
```

But this field is not editable on UI:
[image: ViewModel property Editing.ENABLED]

But it works fine for SimpleObject:
[image: Simple DomainObj property Editing.Enabled]

Does it work correctly for ViewModel?
Maybe ViewModel shouldn't have any properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't working correctly for view models... the framework is meant to support this.

The good news is that there is a workaround.  If you annotate the class to use the (more flexible) JAXB-style of view model, then it all works as expected.

Here's an updated version of the class; look for annotations starting @Xml...:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "compareCustomers")
@XmlType(
    propOrder = {
            "editableField"
    }
)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class HomePageViewModel {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @Setter @Getter
    @Property(editing = Editing.ENABLED)
    private String editableField;

    public TranslatableString title() {
        return TranslatableString.tr("{num} objects", "num", getObjects().size());
    }

    public List<SimpleObject> getObjects() {
        return simpleObjectRepository.listAll();
    }

    @XmlTransient
    @javax.inject.Inject
    SimpleObjectRepository simpleObjectRepository;
}
```

For more on JAXB view models, see the [user guide](http://isis.apache.org/guides/ugfun/ugfun.html#_ugfun_programming-model_view-models).

Meantime I've raised a [JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ISIS-1637) for the issue you've discovered,

Comment: The workaround with JAXB View Model will work only in 1.15.0 version. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44624897/apache-isis-v1-14-0-property-is-not-editable-in-jaxb-view-model