# Apache Isis (v1.14.0): Property is not editable in JAXB view model

Tags: isis

I've created this JAXB view model:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "homePageViewModel")
@XmlType(
        propOrder = {
                "editableField"
        }
)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class HomePageViewModel {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @Setter @Getter
    @Property(editing = Editing.ENABLED)
    private String editableField;

    public TranslatableString title() {
        return TranslatableString.tr("Home page");
    }

    public List<SimpleObject> getObjects() {
        return simpleObjectRepository.listAll();
    }

    @XmlTransient
    @javax.inject.Inject
    SimpleObjectRepository simpleObjectRepository;
}
```

But "editableField" property is not editable:
[image: JAXB viewmodel property]

This question is related to
[Apache Isis: @Property(editing = Editing.ENABLED) doesn't work for ViewModels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44569302/apache-isis-propertyediting-editing-enabled-doesnt-work-for-viewmodels)

Thank you.

Comment: could you try this against 1.15.0-SNAPSHOT ?  I'm pretty certain it works in the latest, but I admit I didn't check against 1.14.0

Comment: You are right, the same JAXB view model works fine in 1.15.0-SNAPSHOT for properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will be fixed in Apache Isis 1.15.0 version.